# First Python CGI working, the one called in its GET method is not working

Tags: python, html, connectivity

My hello.py (working fine) passes data through GET method (can be seen in URL) to test.py (not working).

Test.py working on -bash and gives no error but with http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py it gives an error

> 500 Internal Server Error.

In -bash it gives "EMPTY" as values passed.

Code for test.py (access mode for this file is -rwxrwxrwx@ so that is not an issue)

```
    #!/usr/bin/python   
    import os    
    import cgi    
    import cgitb ;cgitb.enable()    

    form = cgi.FieldStorage()    
    first_name = str(form.getvalue('first_name','EMPTY'))    
    last_name = str(form.getvalue('last_name', 'EMPTY'))    

    print ("Content-Type:text/html\r\n\r\n")    
    print ('<html>')    
    print ('<head>')    
    print ('<title>Second CGI Program</title>')    
    print ('</head>')    
    print ('<body>')    
    print ('Hello %s %s' %(first_name,last_name))    
    print ('</body>')    
    print ('</html>')
```

Comment: It is working, but now it is not reading the values from the URL.....first_name and last_name are None, none

Comment: It works here when I pass the values properly as `http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py?last_name=smith&first_name=john`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!Yes it does for me too. It was not working before because I had written print("first_name") before the html code starts. On removing the print() it started working. Now I am wondering why wasn't the print() working.

Comment: Perhaps you had the `print(first_name)` before the `print("Content-Type:...")`. You have to provide the content-type first before outputting anything else.